# How to transfer data from CoreData on Mac (Xcode) to CoreData on device (iPhone)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have Xcode for iOS development.
Likewise I have the app based on CoreData .sqlite database.
When I launch my app in simulator mode it works well but if I try to do the same on real device - iPhone - I got the error - CoreData store not found.

So my question is: how to migrate / transfer CoreData store (.sqlite) from local Xcode depository to my iPhone?

Comment: Not getting your question, core data work same in simulator and iPhone, try to delete your app and launch again.

Comment: CoreData is persisted on device where it launches (e.g. on simulator / on device)

Comment: Ok , you mean to preload core data on first launch?

Comment: Do you have any custom configuration of your Core Data store?

Comment: check this if it can help you https://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/